# Join MySQL tables on bad table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, concatenation

I have inherited what I suspect is some poor SQL table design and, as an SQL newbie, I'm struggling to come up with a query to join and concatenate the data.

Here are the two tables containing the data:

```
user_space:
+----+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| id | space_1 | space_2 | space_3 | units_s1 | units_s2 | units_s3 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|  1 |     128 |     128 |       6 |        3 |        3 |        4 |
|  2 |       1 |     128 |       2 |        4 |        3 |        4 |
|  3 |     100 |     100 |     100 |        3 |        3 |        3 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
space_units:
+------+--------------+
| type | description  |
+------+--------------+
|    1 | KB           |
|    2 | MB           |
|    3 | GB           |
|    4 | TB           |
+------+--------------+
```

Here is what I'm hoping to be able to produce:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+
| id | total_1 | total_2 | total_3 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 |   128GB |   128GB |     6TB |
|  2 |     1TB |   12GB8 |     2TB |
|  3 |   100GB |   100GB |   100GB |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

The last 3 'units_s*' columns in the user_space table relate to the 'type' column in the space_units table.

Could anyone please help me with a suitable query? I've been at this for ages now and can't figure it out. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to drop the tables and implement them properly.

Comment: The table design you have inherited is better than the table you propose. Better still would be to store all values in integer byte count and format them on select.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select 
    us.id, 
    concat(trim(us.space_1), trim(su1.description)) as total_1,
    concat(trim(us.space_2), trim(su2.description)) as total_2,
    concat(trim(us.space_3), trim(su3.description)) as total_3
from user_space us
inner join space_units su1 on (us.units_s1 = su1.type)
inner join space_units su2 on (us.units_s2 = su2.type)
inner join space_units su3 on (us.units_s3 = su3.type)
order by us.id

+----+---------+---------+---------+
| id | total_1 | total_2 | total_3 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | 128GB   | 128GB   | 6TB     |
|  2 | 1TB     | 128GB   | 2TB     |
|  3 | 100GB   | 100GB   | 100GB   |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

EDIT: Used [Format text as a table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) to format the output

```
create table user_space
(
 id integer,
 space_1 char(5),
 space_2 char(5),
 space_3 char(5),
 units_s1 integer,
 units_s2 integer,
 units_s3 integer
);
insert into user_space values (1, 128,128,6, 3, 3, 4);
insert into user_space values (2, 1,128,2, 4, 3, 4);
insert into user_space values (3, 100,100,100, 3, 3, 3);
create table space_units
(
type integer,
description char(5)
);
insert into space_units values (1, 'KB');
insert into space_units values (2, 'MB');
insert into space_units values (3, 'GB');
insert into space_units values (4, 'TB');
```

EDIT:  [SQL Fiddle for this problem here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e397a/1)